# Can I mock a static method in a final class and a non-static method in a different class using PowerMockito?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, powermock

I have a static method in final class A which calls non-static method in class B.

I need to mock both the static method in A and non-static method in B to add a unit test. Does PowerMock have a solution for such a scenario ?

Comment: What is the need for mocking the method in B?  You could just have the mock of the static method A do everything that is needed in its execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should user PowerMock for mocking the static method in A and Mockito for mocking the non static method in B. In [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289770/mock-up-account-in-activityinstrumentationtestcase2/23682112#23682112) I do both:

- Mock get static method on AccountManager
- Mock getAccounts method also on Account Manager

To be more clear, for the static mock:

1. Add @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) to your test class
2. Add @PrepareForTest(A.class) to your test class
3. Call PowerMockito.mockStatic(AccountManager.class);
4. Stub behavior using when(A.method(any(Param.class))).thenReturn(value);

For the non static mock:

1. Add mock field @Mock B accountManager;
2. Initialize mocks in @Before annotated method MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
3. Stub behavior when(B.method()).thenReturn(value);

Probably you will need to configure the B object on your A class. In this example I'm doing this in the get method. In your case it could be different, you have to figure it out how to do it.

Regards.